# ¿Cómo corregir el error Lost sync to device al ejecutar rosrun?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

Estoy aprendiendo el sistema operativo ROS con un modulo ESP32, comencé con un ejemplo que se encuentra en Arduino "ros_lib", específicamente "Blink", el cual me da el codigo que esta a continuacion:

```
#include <std_msgs/Empty.h>
#define LED_BUILTIN 2

ros::NodeHandle  nh;

void messageCb( const std_msgs::Empty& toggle_msg){
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH-digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN));   // blink the led
}

ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::Empty> sub("Led_conmutador", &messageCb );

void setup()
{ 
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  nh.initNode();
  nh.subscribe(sub);
}

void loop()
{  
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1);
}
```

procedo a cargar el codigo al ESP32 y despues ejcutar el comando **rosrun rosserial_arduino serial_node.py** pero me da este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Investigué un poco y apunta a que la función **sipnOnce** no se llama con frecuencia, pero realmente no sé cuál es el problema real, si es mi ESP32 o el IDE de arduino y mucho menos cómo solucionarlo, si alguien pudiera decirme cual es el problema y como solucionarlo lo agradeceria mucho.

Comment: [Aquí](https://answers.ros.org/question/11237/rosserial-lost-sync-with-device/?answer=16690#post-id-16690) mencionan que deberías llamar la función `spinOnce` frecuentemente. Si la frecuencia no es la suficiente aparecen esos problemas.

Comment: @Mateo, si es lo que pude investigar previamente, pero por que sucede, por que **spinOnce** no se llama frecuentemente es mi  ESP32 o arduino? y como puedo llamar la funcion frecuentemente?